# Change default R library directory on linux

Tags: r, linux

I had an issue on changing the R library on linux. The command I typed in is not working.

```
sudo R -e ".libPaths()"
```

> .libPaths()
>
> [1] "/usr/lib64/R/library" "/usr/share/R/library"

```
sudo R -e ".libPaths(c(.libPaths(), '/usr/test'))"
```

> .libPaths(c(.libPaths(), '/usr/test'))

After that, if I re-run `sudo R -e ".libPaths()"`, I will get the same default path without the new path I added.

Comment: Changes to `.libPaths()` are not persistent across R sessions. See the `?Startup` help pages for the different files that are checked at startup where you can place settings such as the library paths so that future R sessions will use those settings.

Comment: Thanks for the link, which I missed during my initial search. Here is what I did. `cd /usr/lib64/R/etc`, `sudo vim Renviron`, add your directory to `R_LIBS_SITE`.